# Add new data to textbox when selecting item from combobox

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, combobox

How can I automatically input a number to a `textbox` after clicking a `button` upon selecting an item from a `combobox`. All I know to do is to get the data from the `combobox` to `textbox`. But what I would like to do is to add data to a `textbox` once the item is selected.

This is My Code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class voting1

Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim Com As New OleDbCommand
Dim ComInsert As New OleDbCommand
Dim ComUpdate As New OleDbCommand
Dim ComDelete As New OleDbCommand
Dim aAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim Dset As New DataSet

Private Sub voting1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim ConProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=J:\EvS\EVS.accdb"
    Try

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = ConProvider
            If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Open()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No Connection Established")
        End Try

        Me.fill()

        user.Visible = False
        user.Text = Form1.usertxt.Text

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub fill()

    With aAdapter
        .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
        .SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from candidate"
        .SelectCommand.Connection = con
    End With
    Dim dataRead As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    dataRead = aAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While (dataRead.Read())
        presbox.Items.Add(dataRead("President"))
        vpbox.Items.Add(dataRead("VicePresident"))
        secbox.Items.Add(dataRead("Secretary"))
        treasbox.Items.Add(dataRead("Treasurer"))
    End While
    aAdapter.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize()
    Try
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ERROR CONNECTION")

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub bo()
        Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        con1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=J:\EvS\EVS.accdb"
        cmd.Connection = con1
        con1.Open()
        Dim num As Integer
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pres1 FROM vote1"
        If IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar) Then
            num = 1
            samp.Text = num
        Else
            num = 1
            samp.Text = num
        End If
        cmd.Dispose()
        con1.Close()
    con1.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Call Initialize()

        If presbox.Text = "" Or vpbox.Text = "" Or secbox.Text = "" Or treasbox.Text = "" Then

            MsgBox("All Fields are required, Check the fields", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Required Fiels")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        With aAdapter
            .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
            .SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from [vote] where username = '" & user.Text & "'"
            .SelectCommand.Connection = con
        End With

        Dim dataRead As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        dataRead = aAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()


        If Not dataRead.HasRows Then

            ComInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vote([username],[president],[vicePresident],[secretary],[treasurer])" & _
                    "VALUES('" & user.Text & "','" & presbox.Text & "','" & vpbox.Text & "','" & secbox.Text & "','" & treasbox.Text & "')"

            ComInsert.Connection = con
            ComInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Voting Successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "NEW RECORD")

            Form1.Show()
            Me.Close()
            aAdapter.Dispose()
            ComInsert.Dispose()
        Else
            MsgBox("WARNING: User Voted Already!!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR SAVING DATA")
            Me.Close()
            Form1.Show()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to know if an item in combobox is selected or not?

Comment: JLott selectedIndexChanged is a good answer, however I would prefer using javascript to improve page responsiveness and if you already have in the HTML the value you want to put in a textbox I would use HTMLs Select element OnChange event, check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: True, I was coming at it from a VB standpoint and not the web side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this if I am understanding what you are wanting.

1.) We can just check if there is anything in the combobox.text property.

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbobox.text) Then
 Perform the logic of adding data to textbox here.
cbobox.text = null
End If
```

That is the most simple way, but you will have to set the combobox back to null after the data is added to make it work again.

2.) We can make use of the Combobox.SelectedIndexChanged method.

Here is the documentation website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Here is an example:

```
    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
            System.EventArgs e)
        {
perform logic here

        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm .sounds good to me. But heres what i wanna do . I wwnt everything to happen right after i clicked the button. And i got 1 question. Is it possible in vb.net to perform this statement "select count(rooms.rmid) from rooms where rmid= 'bla'"

Comment: So you don't want it to happen when the use selects something? Or you want the button to be clicked... and then wait for the user to select something? Either way the SelectedIndexChanged would work, just either set up a boolean for when the button is clicked or disable to combobox until the button is clicked. And then your question, I assume you mean for a query and yes of course. Dim Query As String = "SELECT COUNT(rooms.rmid) FROM rooms where rmid='bla';"

Comment: Yes . So you mean to say ill put a boolean inside the button click sub? What would it be? Hmmm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could create a boolean and set it to false. Once you click on the button set that to true. Then in your SelectedIndexChanged method, have an if statement that checks to see if that boolean is true. If it is, then you put the data in the textbox. Simple logic :) Just have to think about it.

Comment: oh . i see now i get it . now last thing i tried this . but its now showing any data.     Private Sub p1()
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Com = con.CreateCommand
        Com.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(vote.presnum) as countofpres FROM vote WHERE presnum ='1';"
        Dim dt As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Com.ExecuteReader

        dt.Read()

        Dim countpres As Integer = dt("countofpres")

        Me.pres1.Text = countpres

        dt.Close()

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub p1()
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    Com = con.CreateCommand
    Com.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(vote.presnum) as countofpres FROM vote WHERE presnum ='1';"
    Dim dt As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Com.ExecuteReader

    dt.Read()

    Dim countpres As Integer = dt("countofpres")

    Me.pres1.Text = countpres

    dt.Close()

End Sub
```

here it is Jlott